# How to provide isolation?

Tags: .net, virtualization, isolation, windows-virtual-pc

I have a need to allow my users to execute .NET code that *they provide* on my server. I know security is a big concern, but it has to be done that way.

Currently, I run my users' code under a limited Windows account. But, I am worried that .NET framework provides many classes that, if used maliciously, can harm the server -- classes under the Reflection namespace is one example, CodeDom is another concern.

I wish there was a way to create a "lightweight virtual environment" that can run .NET code, but is fully isolated. Kind of like Virtual PC, but much more lightweight -- the only capability would be that users can do calculations and, possibly, call a 3rd party web service.

Is there something on the market that provides an isolated environment for .NET applications?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but you might consider using Mono on Linux. It doesn't provide perfect .NET functionality, but it could help prevent harm to the server. http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: What kind of code is it and what is it doing? A Winform application, A plugin DLL loaded by your application, a ASP.NET page? It will affect the choices of isolation you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET has built in [security features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx) to do exactly what you want to do. Without knowing how their .NET apps are being launched I can't say for sure if it will help you, but if you control the launching of the apps you can [apply a security context to their AppDomain and restrict what they can access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx#exampleToggle). From what you said in the original posting if you blocked pretty much everything except [WebPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webpermission.aspx) (and you can even restrict it to [specific addresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2ss1wsx.aspx)) it should be safe to run on your system.